# npm run stopped working, but vue-cli-service is after installing plugin

Tags: vue.js

I'm not quite sure what happened, but I've just installed a new plugin via `npm i -S vue-the-mask`.

Now whenever I try running `npm run serve` it returns "Error: Cannot find module 'side-channel'", and logs a bunch of required stack that are already present.

But somehow.. when I run `vue-cli-service serve`, it works perfectly fine. Same issue when running `npm run build` vs `vue-cli-service build`.

I've tried updating npm but it's not fixed still.

Log when running `npm run serve`:

```
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'side-channel'
Require stack:
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/qs/lib/index.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/index.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
Error: Cannot find module 'side-channel'
Require stack:
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/qs/lib/index.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/lib/application.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/express/index.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js
- /Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/User1/Documents/App1/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
```

Content in package.json:

```
     "name": "xxx-v1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "v-wave": "^1.2.8",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```